# SELECT columns from a JOIN while summing rows with a common attribute (MySQL or SQL Server)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

What I want to do is sum each metric of each transaction in the "TRANSACTION" table with a common customer_id in a single query. The output should look like the "OUTPUT" table.

I can see how to select the columns of interest through a JOIN of TRANSACTIONS and CUSTOMER on 'customer_id', but what I don't know is how to sum the metrics at the same time.

---

TRANSACTIONS

```
transaction  customer_id    metric_1    metric_2
1            1              0           564
2            1              0           762
3            1              5.305       8367
4            2              0           150
5            2              3.125       4109
6            2              6.18        1853
7            3              0           61
8            3              0           1
9            3              0           4
```

---

CUSTOMER

```
customer_id   customer_name     
1             XXX       
2             YYY       
3             ZZZ
```

---

DESIRED

```
customer_name   metric_1    metric_2    
XXX             5.305       9693    
YYY             9.305       6112    
ZZZ             0            66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do that using an `Implicit Join`. See my answer below:

```
SELECT 
      customer_name,
      SUM(metric_1) AS metric_1,
      SUM(metric_2) AS metric_2 
FROM Transactions,Customer
WHERE Transactions.customer_id=Customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_name
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35024f/1/0)

Comment: Although this is correct, I would suggest you to refrain from using old-style JOIN syntax. See this article by Aaron Bertrand: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just want to show @mattk62586 an another approach to solve his problem aside from your answers. Thanks for that. +1 for your answer ^_^.

Comment: No problem. Glad we're on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUM` and group by `customer_id` and `customer_name`.

```
SELECT
    c.customer_name,
    metric_1 = SUM(t.metric_1),
    metric_2 = SUM(t.metric_2)
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Customer c
    ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
GROUP BY t.customer_id, c.customer_name
```